# How to make a shape larger or smaller without changing the resolution of the image using OpenCV or PIL in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I would like to be able to make a certain shape in either a PIL image or an OpenCV image 3 times larger and smaller without changing the resolution of the image or changing the shape of the shape I want to make larger. I have tried using OpenCV's dilation method but that is not it's intended use, plus it changed the shape of the image. For an example:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: So, you want to `extract` the object, `vectorize` it, `scale` it by `s`, `rasterize` it and then paste it back onto the original canvas? Are anti-aliased objects needed in your application?

Comment: @eldesgraciado That sounds about Right. The object will be upscaled and used as a mask to capture a portion of another screen. Then it is downsized to the original shape. The upscaled version doesn’t have to be anti-aliased, but the Down scaled version I would like to be smoothed.

Comment: Why resizing the image using NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR work in this case?

Comment: Is your image really representative? What happens if the object is irregularly shaped and not in the centre - where/how does the new object appear?

Comment: Is the background always pure white? Is the shape always a single solid colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way of doing it:

- find the interesting shape, i.e. non-white ROI area
- extract it
- scale it up by a factor
- clear the original image to white
- paste the scaled ROI back into image with same centre

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Open image
    orig = cv2.imread('image.png',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # Get extent of interesting part, i.e. non-white part
    y, x, _ = np.nonzero(~orig)
    y0, y1 = np.min(y), np.max(y)    # top and bottom rows
    x0, x1 = np.min(x), np.max(x)    # left and right cols
    h, w = y1-y0, x1-x0              # height and width
    ROI = orig[y0:y1, x0:x1]         # extract ROI
    cv2.imwrite('ROI.png', ROI)      # DEBUG only

    # Upscale ROI
    factor = 3
    scaledROI = cv2.resize(ROI, (w*factor,h*factor), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    newH, newW = scaledROI.shape[:2]

    # Clear original image to white
    orig[:] = [255,255,255]

    # Get centre of original shape, and position of top-left of ROI in output image
    cx, cy = (x0 + x1) //2, (y0 + y1)//2
    top  = cy - newH//2
    left = cx - newW//2

    # Paste in rescaled ROI
    orig[top:top+newH, left:left+newW] = scaledROI
    cv2.imwrite('result.png', orig)
```

That transforms this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Puts me in mind of a pantograph:

[image]

Comment: This works! Now I'll just have to implement it. Thanks!